# SQL Server : bring up columns from a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I am pretty stuck with this (SQL Server 2008 R2).

I have a tables called orders:

`Orders`:

```
orderid  details
--------------------
1        my order
```

I then have a custom fields table.

`Custom_fields`:

```
rel_orderid  fieldname  numericvalue  textvalue  datevalue
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            auction    0             My auction
1            date       0                        01/01/2014
```

I am trying to get

```
orderid   details   auction     date (on one row)
-------------------------------------------------
1         my order  my auction  01/01/2014
```

Hope that makes sense but I'm beat how to wrap up the `custom_fields` table into column headers and then only have 1 value (could be text value or date etc - only 1 will have data)

The auction and date and read form the fieldname column and then the values for each.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max` with `case` for this:

```
select o.orderid, 
       o.details, 
       max(case when c.fieldname = 'auction' then textvalue end) auction,
       max(case when c.fieldname = 'date ' then datevalue end) datevalue 
from orders o
       join custom_fields c on o.orderid = c.rel_orderid  
group by o.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

you can PIVOT in such a case.

```
select orderid,
       details,
       [auction],  
       [date]
FROM
(
      select rel_orderid as orderid,
             o.details, 
             fieldname, 
             (case when fieldname = 'auction'
                     then textvalue
                     when fieldname ='date' 
                     then cast(datevalue AS varchar(128))
                     end) value
       FROM custom_fields
       INNER JOIN orders o
       on o.orderid = rel_orderid
) As OrderDetails 
PIVOT
(
        max(value) 
        for fieldname in ([auction],[date])
) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid an aggregation, you can do this using joins:

```
select o.orderid, o.details, a.textvalue as auction, d.datevalue as dateval
from orders o left join
     custom_fields a
     on a.rel_orderid = o.orderid and a.fieldname = 'auction' left join
     custom_fields d
     on d.rel_orderid = o.orderid and d.fieldname = 'date';
```

The `left join` gives a value (`NULL`) even if there is no match.